# Crawl Rule Regular expression to exclude Thank you Pages in pages in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-search

Hi I have the following URLs:

//site/us/count/Pages/product-a-Thank-you. //site/us/count/Pages/Information-b-Thank-you
//site/us/count/Pages/register-c-Thank-you //site/us/count/Pages/link-d-Thank-you. //site/us/world/Pages/link-e-Thank-you.html //site/us/world/Pages/Register-h-Thank-you.html

I want a rule that excludes the above URLs for which are ending in thank-you
Can someone help me out? I've been looking at this all morning?

Answer (score 0):

USe negative lookahead like below.

```
(?i)^(?!.*\bthank-you$).*
```

Without `(?i)` case insensitive modifier.

```
^(?!.*\bThank-you$).*
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/mI5dQ1/5)